# How to Align all elements inside a class with boolean condition in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <input class="first" [ngClass]="{ 'first': !checked , 'new-first' : checked}">
      <input class="second" [ngClass]="{ 'first': !checked , 'new-second' : checked}">
    </div>
    <div>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked"></mat-checkbox>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 50%;
}
.first {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
.second {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 45%;
}

.new-first {
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
.new-second {
  background-color: brown;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

COMPONENT TS

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  checked:boolean = false;
}
```

I have two input fields column wise, and i have one checkbox, if i check the checkbox it becomes true so with the help of [ngClass] create a new class, so if it true alignment of the div is same, if it false then go to previous position, but its not working.

here is the stackblitz example link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cnevqu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

[example image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpYPX.png),
[example image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIgPr.png)

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve from your question and the stackblitz example. Could you describe it better or provide a UI mock-up?

Comment: I have two input field inside a parent div, at last I have one checkbox, initially the two input fields positions are different, u can see clearly in stackblitz and from image, with the help of [ngClass] creating conditional classes true means class 'first' false means class 'new-first', so when I check the checkbox, checked value is true , class 'first' css work then uncheck class 'new-first' css work, but the positions are not same i need to align same.

Comment: What are these 'positions' that you are talking? where do you want your inputs to be placed?

Comment: center and same column

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you missed was that you tried to assign `class="first"` to the first input, which made it static. All you need is `[ngClass]="expression ? 'true-class' : 'false-class' "`.

##### app.component.html

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input [ngClass]="checked ? 'new-first' : 'first'">
  <input [ngClass]="checked ? 'new-second' : 'second'">
</div>

<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked"></mat-checkbox>
```

As for the css, you shouldn't use `float`. You should use `align-self` if you want to align the inputs to the left or right of the `parent` div.

When the checkbox is `false` (not checked), `first` and `second` class is applied, so the inputs align to left and to the right respectively.

When the checkbox is `true`, the `new-first` and `new-second` class is applied. Because the `parent` class has `align-items: center`, both inputs automatically got centered.

##### app.component.css

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.first {
  align-self: start;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.second {
  align-self: end;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.new-first {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.new-second {
  background-color: brown;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}
```